# How to pin Visual Studio 2013 projects to start menu tasks

Tags: start-menu, tasks, visual-studio-2013, pinning

I am using Windows 7

I have pinned **Google Chrome** to my start menu and I can see a right arrow near the icon. When hovering on it I can see tasks as `new window and new incognito window`.

Likewise I need to add most commonly worked projects in Visual Studio 2013 to the `Visual Studio launcher in Start menu`.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Mine does this automatically. I assume you have pinned VS 2013 by locating it in the start menu, right click, pin to start menu?

Comment: Make sure you open the file in Visual Studio from the File-> Open, not the recently opened panel.

Answer (score 4):

I found out the answer.

- First I pinned Visual Studio to Task bar.
- Second, dragged the solution file and dropped on the exe on the Task
  bar (Pinned to Visual Studio)

After the second step, I was able to see the programs to the right side (tasks) of the Visual Studio short cut in the start menu.

Comment: Thank you!  Not having specific .sln files available from the right-click menu of a pinned taskbar exe was really annoying me.